# Using htmlParse to clean text from dataframe

Tags: html, r, html-parsing, rstudio

I have a dataFrame with HTML text in one column and a binary variable in the other column. Looks like this in the first column:

```
1 <p>I am trying to build a simple map app with Shiny and ggplot2. It works as follow: </p>\n\n<ul>\n<li>user selects a country </li>\n<li>the app loads a shape file and gives a list of input fields for adm1 country regions</li>\n<li>user inputs a numeric value for each region (fields are initially filled with random values) </li>\n<li>all values from input fields are collected in a vector, merged to the map data and given as a <code>fill</code> argument to the <code>ggplot()</code> function</li>\n</ul>\n\n<p>The problem is that ggplot doesn't seem to interpret correctly the input values for each regions. Plus, colors on the map don't change when input values are modified through the UI. I believe the  <code>indicator</code> vector fed to the <code>fill</code> argument is not correctly interpreted/passed.</p>\n\n<p>Thank you for your suggestions.</p>\n\n<p><em>Note: in the code below, the shapefiles are sourced on the UCDavis website for reproducibility. I usually store them locally.</... <truncated>
```

I'm trying to clean, or remove the HTML tags using a for loop, but R is saying this isn't XML code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataFrame)) {
  row <- dataFrame[i,]
  htmlParse(dataFrame)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `gsub('<[^>]+>', '', x)` ?

Comment: That removes some, but not everything, thank you though!

Comment: it works for your example, we can't tell what you really want if you don't say

Comment: Sorry, newb here, I included more of the HTML code, it seems like it removes most of the HTML code involving <>, but I still have a lot of weird formatting issues. I also tried the extractHTMLstrip() function from the tm.plugin.webmining package and got a similar result.